# Panel data: Create a dummy that identify groups with specific row value in another variable. Efficient approach

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am using a database that looks like this:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm") 
library(dplyr)
Grunfeld<-Grunfeld%>%filter(year<=1940)
head(Grunfeld,10)
#     firm year inv value    capital
# 1     1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8
# 2     1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6
# 3     1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9
# 4     1 1938 257.7 2792.2   209.2
# 5     1 1939 330.8 4313.2   203.4
# 6     1 1940 461.2 4643.9   207.2
# 7     2 1935 209.9 1362.4    53.8
# 8     2 1936 355.3 1807.1    50.5
# 9     2 1937 469.9 2676.3   118.1
# 10    2 1938 262.3 1801.9   260.2
```

I am trying to create a new variable `cap38` based on the following conditions:

1) If the capital of a firm is above 160 in 1938 the variable takes the value of 1 otherwise 0.

2) The variable should identify firms that have capital above 160 in 1938 (not observations). In other words, if the firm meets the first condition, `cap38` should score 1 for the firm across all the panel, not just for the year 38.

I am able to obtain the results I want with this approach

```
# first I identify firms that meet conditions, 
sm<-Grunfeld%>%filter(capital>160 & year==1938) %>% mutate(cap38=1) %>%
  select(firm,cap38) %>%distinct()

# then I join this data with the original database
Grunfeld<-left_join(Grunfeld,sm)

# finally I replace missing observations with 0s
library(data.table)
setDT(Grunfeld)[is.na(cap38),cap38:=0]
head(Grunfeld,10)
    firm year   inv  value capital cap38
 1:    1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8     1
 2:    1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6     1
 3:    1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9     1
 4:    1 1938 257.7 2792.2   209.2     1
 5:    1 1939 330.8 4313.2   203.4     1
 6:    1 1940 461.2 4643.9   207.2     1
 7:    2 1935 209.9 1362.4    53.8     1
 8:    2 1936 355.3 1807.1    50.5     1
 9:    2 1937 469.9 2676.3   118.1     1
10:    2 1938 262.3 1801.9   260.2     1
```

This produces the expected result, as both firm 1 and 2 meet the condition they have a score of 1 for every time period. I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way to do so. Ideally, using a data.table approach.

I have tried something like this:

```
setDT(Grunfeld)[capital>160 & year==1938,cap38_worng:=1
                ][is.na(cap38_worng),cap38_worng:=0]
head(Grunfeld,10)
    firm year   inv  value capital cap38 cap38_worng
 1:    1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8     1           0
 2:    1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6     1           0
 3:    1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9     1           0
 4:    1 1938 257.7 2792.2   209.2     1           1
 5:    1 1939 330.8 4313.2   203.4     1           0
 6:    1 1940 461.2 4643.9   207.2     1           0
 7:    2 1935 209.9 1362.4    53.8     1           0
 8:    2 1936 355.3 1807.1    50.5     1           0
 9:    2 1937 469.9 2676.3   118.1     1           0
10:    2 1938 262.3 1801.9   260.2     1           1
```

The problem with this approach is that it only identifies observations that meet my condition but not firms. For instance for firm 1, `cap38_worng` is =0 in 1937, while is =1 in 1938

Hopefully, this is an easy question for those that are most skilled. But I am struggling to find an efficient way to solve my problem.

I thank you in advance for your help

best regards

Comment: `Grunfeld <- Grunfeld %>% 
  mutate(cap38 = case_when(capital>160 & year==1938 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) `?

Comment: Dear amatsuo, it appears that your solution results in something similar to `cap38_worng`. do you have suggestions to obtain something similar to `cap38`?

Comment: Now I know what you want. I will post something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can check if there is a `firm` where `capital > 160` when `year == 1938`.

We can do this using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
Grunfeld %>% 
  group_by(firm) %>%  
  mutate(cap38 = as.integer(any(capital > 160 & year == 1938)))
```

Base R :

```
Grunfeld$cap38 <- +(with(Grunfeld, ave(capital > 160 & year == 1938,
                                   firm, FUN = any)))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Grunfeld)[, cap38 := as.integer(any(capital > 160 & year == 1938)), firm]
```

Comment: Dear Ronak, thank you for your reply, unfortunately, these approaches do not appear to produce the expected result but rather they produce a result similar to `cap38_wrong`. I have updated the explanation to show the problem. I hope it helps

Comment: @Alex I see. I updated the answer. Can you check that? Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to check whether there is a case when `(capital>160 & year==1938)` at **the firm level**. Here is one way to do that.

```r
library(plm)
library(tidyverse)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")

Grunfeld <- Grunfeld %>% 
  filter(year <= 1940) %>%
  group_by(firm) %>% # grouping by firm
  # check if there is the case within the firm with capital > 160 in year 1938
  mutate(cap38 = max(capital>160 & year==1938)) 

head(Grunfeld)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#> # Groups:   firm [1]
#>    firm  year   inv value capital cap38
#>   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1  1935  318. 3078.     2.8     1
#> 2     1  1936  392. 4662.    52.6     1
#> 3     1  1937  411. 5387.   157.      1
#> 4     1  1938  258. 2792.   209.      1
#> 5     1  1939  331. 4313.   203.      1
#> 6     1  1940  461. 4644.   207.      1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>